# Transactional Replication: Maintaining schema changes

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016, transactional-replication

Whats the best approach to not to break replication but still apply schema changes to Primary and Secondary ? (not just DDL, new articles etc)

We have a huge database, so we had to go with replication using a back-up. The process is time consuming (2-3 hours). Each release we have tons of schema changes, as we are in active dev mode, we don't want to waste 2-3 hours to redo the process all over again and again.

Any suggestions or ideas ?

Comment: can you pause the flow of data or make all changes 100% backwards compatible in a 2 phase or other approach?

Comment: Answers is no. Dev ops, doesn't want to any manual intervention. And we don't want to pause replication

Comment: looks like you're going to have to stick to making all changes backwards compatible then.  Is your real question at this moment 'why do replicated columns are being dropped on the subscriber when dropped on the publisher, even when schema change replication is turned off'.  Is that correct?

Comment: @AliRazeghi Well, you read my mind, wanted to post it as different post.

Comment: @AliRazeghi this being said, we might be going toward always on availability groups. which needs lots of configuration

Comment: in some ways, AGs are less complex than transaction replication, esp. in terms of schema updates.  In other ways it causes more complexity such as reindexing and having to get familiar with WSFC.  I would support AGs all the way most of the time.

Answer (score 1):

With transactional replication you must ensure that your schema changes are [compatible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/make-schema-changes-on-publication-databases?view=sql-server-2017) or risk errors on the subscriber.  In practice this means reviewing the schema change scripts and testing their compatibility with your replication topology.  Adding articles requires a new snapshot, but you can create a second publication to hold the added tables if you want to reduce the snapshot size.

If you don't want to do that, then a log-based replica is probably a better design.  See, eg Read [Scale Availability Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/read-scale-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks David, totally agree with you. We had an approach where could add schema changes first on the subscriber and later on primary, (with replication of schema changes turned off). But drops(columns) are being replicated no matter what. (which i don't understand why).